# Error when Discord.js cannot find an item in an array with mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, typeerror, discord.js

I am receiving this error:

```
    C:\Users\redacted\Downloads\redacted\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^ 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reason' of undefined
  at Query.con.query (C:\Users\redacted\Downloads\redacted\bot.js:83:30)
```

This is my code:

```
const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
        let member = args.slice(0, 1).join(' ');
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM bans WHERE id=${member}`, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log("check here "+member);
            let reason;
            reason = rows[0].reason;
            if(reason="undefined") return message.reply(`I did not find any users with that ID banned. You must check by user ID!`);
            if(reason) return message.reply(`I found the user banned for the reason **${reason}**`);
```

I am pretty lost here. Basically, I need it to look for an item in a database. Its comparing the column named "id" with a given with the command +check (id here). Then, if it finds one, it pulls the "reason" on the same row of the id. The problem is, when +check is ran but it does not find an ID matching a given ID it crashes the Discord bot and gives that error. I am throwing the error (I think). I am fairly new to mySQL so sorry if this is just a simple mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? In case of that error happening, what does `rows` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the case of no rows found:

```
const row = rows[0];

if (row) {
  const { reason } = row;
  // rest of your code
} else {
  // no rows found
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem 100%. This also is something I would have to reuse in a key component of this bot. Thank you very very much!